# NO NETBEANS PROJECTS ADDED warning

Tags: java, netbeans, github, zip, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to import a projetc (in ZIP file) in my netbeans. It is downloaded from GitHub (link: https://github.com/varavell/OnlineBookStore). While importing the project from Zip it shows the error and no project becomes imported. At the same time, at the bottom right corner it keeps unpacking of the project (never finish it though). Why this happening and how can I run a complete project into netbeans?

The worning is:

[image]

Comment: Try this: 
1.Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N on Windows/Cmd-Shift-N on OS X).
2.Choose Java > Java Project with Existing Sources.

For further details, look at https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes#projects-importing

Answer (score 1):

This warning (No NetBeans projects added) can happen if the zip file was created manually. To avoid this create the ZIP file in NetBeans using File > Export Project > To Zip...

Answer (score 0):

Unzip your project and then open Netbeans. Go to File > open > your project file

Comment: NB can do mpprt from zip directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know what the problem is from the information you're providing.

It might be that the zip is corrupted, that the zip is not correct, that the zip contains a project in an unrecognized format, or that it's a bug with netbeans, for example.

You need to provide the NetBeans' log at least. I'm currently on cellphone, so i can't tell you where to fimd it, but you can find it yourself after a simple google search.

---

As for an immediate solution, since the project is on GitHub, you can simply ***clone*** the project using ***Git*** (inside NB). Or create a new project and manually replicate the files from the source-codes and file-structure visible on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one of the projects that Netbeans recognizes in the zip file.

This particular project has no pom.xml, build.xml or nbproject directory.

You will need to create a new project of the appropriate type and extact/copy your sources from the zip into it.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify which GitHub project he is importing. How can you be sure that *"This particular project has no pom.xml, build.xml or nbproject directory"*? Couldn't it also be due to file corruption or from the zip being the wrong one file (not containing a project, regardless of NB's recognition), etc...?

Comment: Oh, nvm...You can see the name of the zip file on the progress-bar in the attached image, right? Sorry, I'm on phone, so I didn't notice the fine details.

Comment: hi i have updated the link where i am downloading the project from.

Comment: The OP can simply ***clone*** the repository to a local branch using NB's ***Git support***. It's much easier than replicating (copying) manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to import a web project. first of all plugin web tools JSF, RichFaces etc. and then you will import your NetBeans web files.
and then Export Project > To Zip.

Answer (score -1):

You should extract your project from the zip first. Then add it from file system.

Comment: Using the import zip menu option is essentially the same as this.  In this case there won't be any project to open even after the zip is extracted.

Comment: hi thank u for the answer. but if u see file>import project>from Zip is also an option, so it should have worked. I dont know why. Now coming back to ur point if I unzip and try to open file, it doesn't. It just keeps going inside the folder to folder untill it gets empty.

Comment: Are you sure you zip contains NetBeans project?